# ¿Cómo puedo consultar si existe un elemento de una tabla en otra tabla en mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito ver la posibilidad de tomar dos columnas concatenadas de un registro de una tabla (A) y ver si este registro concatenado existe en una columna llamada descripción de la tabla (B).

Se tiene la tabla (A) en donde se quiere concatenar la columna "nombre" y "version" para ver si este registro concatenado se encuentra en la columna "descripcion" de la tabla (B).

[image: Tabla (A)]

[image: Tabla (B)]

¿Es posible realizar esta acción solo en una consulta de mysql?

Comment: Es posible,  y relativamente fácil hacer lo que quieres. ¿Has investigado/intentado algo? ¿Qué problemas tienes en base a ese intento o qué no entiendes de lo que has investigado?

Comment: @A.Cedano si he investigado, he intentado realizar una consulta utilizando php para concatenar las columnas y posteriormente utilizar otra consulta utilizando LIKE en php. Sin embargo, el problema que me genera es que para esto trabajo con el método de fetch_assoc() de php y si pongo 2 consultas que impliquen el resultado me da error de ejecución en la consulta, por eso estoy buscando la opción de hacerlo directamente con una consulta mysql sin usar php de intermedio.

Comment: Una cosa no tiene que ver con la otra. O sea, una vez la consulta funcione (en la base de datos) puedes pasar por PHP **si lo necesitas** para manejar esos datos (sin importar cómo sea la consulta). Considero importante aclarar eso, porque tu comentario hace pensar que PHP y SQL son dos universos alternativos y no lo son, más bien son complementarios. Prueba tu consulta en SQL, usando por ejemplo lo que sugiere @JavierGarcia. Luego, si funciona, el que debas usar PHP o no es otro asunto.

Answer (score 1):

Por tu ultimo comentario puedes usar la función `concat` de mysql y hacer un join

```
SELECT A.nombre, A.version, B.descripcion FROM tablaB as B 
INNER JOIN tablaA as A 
ON b.descripcion like CONCAT('%',A.nombre,' ',A.version,'%');
```

Revisa si no afecta el rendimiento, ya que se puede mejorar.
El `string` de búsqueda concatenado quedaría así: `%Apache 2.0.22%` separado por un espacio.

Comment: muchas gracias... pude solucionar el problema que tenía utilizando tu consulta.